# How to create a ultra light modal in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

Is there a possibility to create a full fledged, responsive jQuery modal without using plugin online? Exclusion CSS can be unlimited.

Comment: You can create a full fledged, responsive, popup with `1 line` of code

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to create a full fledged, responsive, popup
>   with not more than 6 lines of jQuery?

I've a good news for you. You don't need jQuery for it. And it's just a sinlge line. You can show something, ask something, or ask their choice.

```
confirm("Did you like my answer?"); // Press OK!
alert("Alert! There's a fire in your browser!!!");
prompt("What's your try?");
```

Such features, much wow.

Comment: HI, Thanks.... it is useful. But in UI point of view this cannot be used in the current web. You can see my answer for the best possible way.

Comment: do you even sarcasm mate? :-)

Comment: I am not. But my point of question was different that is why you got this comment. Thanks for the negative point.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the answer

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="show1" id="popup1">
<div class="simple_popup_container" id="popup1_popup">
   <div class="simple_popup_close">x</div>
    <div class="simple_popup_body">You can write any content the width will automatically adjust.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{margin:0;}

.Simple_popup_wrapper {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index:9999999;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.simple_popup_container {
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
    max-width:95%;
    position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.simple_popup_close {
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:-10px -10px 0px 0px;
    background:#fff;
    height:20px;
    width:14px;
    border-radius:30px;
    padding:2px 0px 0px 8px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    color: #999;
    font-family: arial;
}
.simple_popup_close:hover {
    background:#000;
    color: #fff;
}
.simple_popup_body {
    min-height:300px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.simple_popup_container').hide();

var simple_popup_open = function () {$('#' + this.id + '_popup').fadeIn(300).wrap($("<div></div>").addClass("Simple_popup_wrapper")); };
$('.simple_popup_close').click(function () {$('.simple_popup_container').hide().unwrap(); });

// Please add your popup id here
$("#popup2, #popup1").click(simple_popup_open);

});

</script>
```

Comment: If you get a plugin online you should at least get 100 lines more code js file to include a popup in your html